# Configuring MikroTik RB 750 GL to have switch as WAN and Ether1 as NAT to LAN

Tags: networking, firewall, mikrotik, routeros

My ISP allows me to have multiple static IP addresses. I want to use a RouterBoard 750GL to attach multiple publicly addressable servers to the internet using Ether[2-5] in switch mode, and use Ether1 for the LAN. Is this even possible to configure with RouterOS, or do I need to purchase a separate switch? If it is possible, how do I go about making this configuration? I am a RouterOS newb. Here is a picture to clarify what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just make 3 interfaces connected with your servers and the one that is connected to your internet in same switch/bridge.

> You can create a bridge and remove all out of switch mode and put the 4 interfaces in the bridge,it acts like the switch (software buffer).

and make sure your Lan interface is not in the switch or bridge with the other.
then assign public IP addresses you want with your servers, and assign one public IP address with mikrotik itself ,to make it able to NAT your LAN traffic.